# How to copy a attribute of another model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to copy the `email` attribute from `User` using after create, but in the logs i get an error.

The method that I'm trying is:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible  :email, :engine

  after_create :get_email

  def get_email
    email = user.email.dup
  end
end
```

Someone can spare a hint?

Comment: Please post your error log.

Comment: ok, just a moment

Comment: sorry did not show the error, but did not copy the attribute

Comment: So, you expect get_email to return a shallow copy of user.email object. What do you actually get in the variable email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things missing in your code:

1. `self` is needed to set the value for `email`.
2. The object needs to be saved after setting `email`.

So, after adding `self` and `save`, your `get_email` method should look like this:

```
def get_email
  self.email = user.email
  save
end
```

Notice that also `dup` has been removed, since it is not needed to copy the value (more information about `dup` [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-dup)).

---

That said, i recommend using `before_create` action instead of `after_create`:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible  :email, :engine

  before_create :get_email

  def get_email
    self.email = user.email
  end
end
```

With `:before_crete` you will copy the `email` from `User` and only will need to save your object once. If you do it with `:after_create`, first you will save the object, then look for the `email` in `User` and then will need to execute an additional `update` (i.e save again).

Comment: thank you gerry! but i don't know why the email still nil, this email is the car email that i'm trying to copy from user email

Comment: Ok, so you want to copy the `email` from the related `User` and save it in `email` attribute in current `Car` object?

Comment: Actually, the `self` is only needed when assigning a value to a setter method (otherwise Ruby would create a local variable), but not when reading. Therefore you can change the line setting the email to `self.email = user.email`

Comment: @spickermann Oh, you're right. I'll update my anwer. Than you.